# Filter Pandas Dataframe that is an array

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have a data frame that I'd like to filter by a column that is of type array. What is the most effective way to do this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5], 'b': [['true','false'],['false'],['false','false','false'],['false','false','true'],[]]})
df

    a   b
0   1   [true, false]
1   2   [false]
2   3   [false, false, false]
3   4   [false, false, true]
4   5   []
```

I'd ideally like to only return rows that contain a true value.

Comment: `array` is not a `dtype`. There no real effective way to work with lists in `pandas.DataFrame`'s, but you could always do something like `df[df.b.apply(lambda x: 'true' in x)]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga would using `any()` be more performant?

Comment: @pault well, if they are actualy `numpy.ndarray` objects instead of `list` objects, maybe slightly, but the time sink is iterating over the rows, which is necessitated in this case. Furthermore, those arrays would be `dtype=object` anyway, so iteration would still be slow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without loop :-)

```
df[pd.DataFrame(df.b.tolist()).eq('true').any(1)]
Out[98]: 
   a                     b
0  1         [true, false]
3  4  [false, false, true]
```

Comment: Wonderful answer... very impressive.